# Best method to work in R program

Tags: r, shiny

I have planned to start my R program carrier now. I have understand the usage R but i have some doubts on the procedure to be implement in R. As a startup i am planing to retrieve data from google analytics and show it to frontend using R shiny. So which will be the good flow to fetch the data. Is it good to fetch the google analytic data using R and process it or it will be good to fetch the data using other languages like php or Java. Also R is good to fetch the data from database or its a good practice to fetch the data using other commonly used languages and process using R.

Sorry the question is little bit descriptive but i am expecting a help from you guys
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Organize it in a package(http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/).

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/r-google-analytics?hl=en .

The database question depends on exactly what you are using, but R has a lot of resources.